# What are the options for open source Mobile VPN solution?

Tags: vpn, open-source

I looking for open source mobile VPN solutions. Not regular VPN solutions like OpenVPN. My need is that VPN tunnel should not get disrupted when endpoint switches networks (aka when moved from wired n/w to wireless). I had faced this issue with openVPN, where whenever i switch my route to internet from cellular modem to Wi-Fi hotspot, my connection to VPN server will get broken and restart. Refer this [question](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic20229.html). This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_virtual_private_network) states that Mobile VPN will be persistent event if clients are roaming across various networks. I would like to try mobile VPN and verify whether i can able to alleviate the above problem. For a start, Open source Mobile VPN solution will be the easy way. What are the options i have? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand what Mobile VPN actually is. In spite of its name, it has nothing to do with you setting up an (IP) VPN on your mobile device.

Mobile VPN is a means for cellular providers to create a secured network segment for their business customers on cellular network systems. It's not something you do on your end.

What you want is simply a VPN client that automatically reconnects. But that's another question and I suggest you first do some research on it.

Comment: This[link link](www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/ios-nx-os-software/mobile-vpn/index.html) says nothing about role of cellular provider or cellular network system and it only gives me the idea of Mobile VPN being nothing but a VPN which is mobile. As the line _"Users don't need to continually restart and reauthenticate the connection or any intranet applications running on it."_ suggests.

Comment: Event the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_virtual_private_network) also doesn't quote any reference to cellular network system in mobile VPN. Could you share some content supporting your answer? So that it will be clear to me.

Comment: It seems to me you are focussing on the sentences you find most interesting and somehow just tune out the rest. The first sentence of your Cisco reference says "Cisco Mobile VPN is a Cisco IOS IP Mobility solution". That should make it clear that their "Mobile VPN" is really just an extension to "Mobile IP" - which by itself is tunnel based. But you cannot have the former without the latter. Read up on Mobile IP on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_IP